# IIS 5 default website (Stopped) after new install on new box

Tags: windows-xp, asp.net, iis

We just got new boxes at work.

Running Xp, IIs 5.1 (yeah I know corporate decision, not mine)

when I go look at inetmgr (iis) the default website it stopped.
if restarted, I get an error that it didn't respond in a timely manor

I ran netstat -an, and -o and saw nothing had port 80 open.

cleared my event viewer, restarted iis and restarted iisadmin service (and theirby smtp)
no errors in the event log.

I ran aspnet_regiis -i jsut in case.

Still no joy.

I'm stumped.

Can any think of anything else to try?

Thanks,

E-

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out..

a bunch of services required were disabled in the image from HP
so we had to turn them all on and set a bunch of permissions to get it running.